# Fill select list with values depending on preselection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have one select list populated with different values (price) depending on which option was chosen in other select list (sale or rent)

So what I have done is first create the arrays for sale and rent.

Then get the jquery and do an change event to pick which selection was made.

then a Switch statement that should populate the select list in question, but it is not showing anything. While jquery is a library for javascript I dont know if mixing them like I have done is alright:

```js
    $('#transaction').change(function(){        
       $value = $('#transaction').val();
    var sale = [];
    for (var i = 350000; i <= 2000000; i+100000) {
        sale.push(i);
    }

    var rent = [];
    for (var i = 500; i <= 6000; i+100) {
        rent.push(i);
    }
        
      switch($value) {
        case 'sale':       
    $.each(sale, function(key, value){                 
    $('#price').append('<option value="' + index+ '">' + value + '</option>')             
            break;        
        case 'rent':       
            break;
        }); // end of each    
      } // end of switch
}) ; //end of jquery snippet
```

```html
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('transaction', 'Transaction')}}
        <select name="transaction" id="transaction" class="form-control">
            <option value="select">Select</option>
            <option value="sale">Sale</option>
            <option value="rent">Rent</option>
            <option value="holiday">Holiday</option>
        </select>
      
      </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('price', 'Price')}}
        <select name="price" id="price" class="form-control">
        </select>          
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: I think you added something wrong by mistake. can you verify

Comment: Please indicate which other library/framework you are using for resolving `{{...}}`.

Comment: oh that is Laravel, I have removed it because that is just to echo the label but has no effect on the select list itsef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credits go to Keith Wood (Sydney)

```
$(function() {
    $('#transaction').change(function() {
        var sale = [];
        for (var i = 350000; i <= 2000000; i += 100000) {
        sale.push(i);
        }
        var rent = [];
        for (var i = 500; i <= 6000; i += 100) {
        rent.push(i);
        }
        var option = $('#transaction').val();
    var prices = (option === '1' ? sale : (option === '2' ? rent : []));
        var options = '';
        $.each(prices, function(key, value) {                 
      options += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>';
        });
        $('#price').html(options);
    });
});


<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('street', 'Transaction')}}
        <select name="transaction" id="transaction" class="form-control">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            <option value="1">Sale</option>
            <option value="2">Rent</option>
            <option value="3">Holiday</option>
        </select>

      </div>
      </div>



<div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('price', 'Price')}}
        <select name="price" id="price" class="form-control">
        </select>

      </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont have the options element in your select tag, so it never gets  the $value from this statement :- `$value = ('#transaction').val();`

Insert the option tags and then run your example.

Comment: I dont see sale and rent in select tag on jsfiddle

Comment: try this at the beginning of your change function:-$value = ('#transaction').val();
alert($value);

Comment: Very good now change the following line in switch statement:-   $('#price').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>')

Comment: try using index instead of key in each loop

Comment: No! An array is not a key value pair. An array is a index value pair. So try using index instead of key for the sale an rental array

Comment: what about syntactical errors. Check for any missing semi-colons or curly braces. I dont see semicolon after alert statement. If the alert doesnt  show up it means missing brackets or curly braces

Comment: You have some syntax errors in your code. Edit the code so that I can see the changes on this page